# Russian symbols in console in QNX system become unreadable after QT application runs

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qnx

I have an x86 QNX 6.5.0 system with Russian localization, and such things like date and time in console, or login (username and password invitation) are in Russian. However if I run any QT application and then close it to get back to console all Russian words (including previous output) change to something unreadable.

How to resolve it?

Comment: What language are you using - C++, Python, something else? It's good to tag your question with the language.

Comment: Probably utf/koir/cp1251 encoding issues..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try next:

`QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");`

and  for example

`setWindowTitle(codec->toUnicode("Окно выбора параметра"));`

?